# Polynomial with no roots of unity among its roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, roots-of-unity

I am reading a paper which states without proof that, for $r \ge 2$, the polynomial $f(X) = X^r - X^{r-1}- X^{r-2} - \ldots - 1$ has no roots (in $\Bbb{C}$) that are roots of unity. After playing around with elementary algebra and getting nowhere, I tried to apply the methods of this [note by Keith Conrad on polynomials with roots on the unit circle](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/numbersoncircle.pdf) , but with no success. I suspect there is something very simple that I am missing. Any clues about how to prove this will be very gratefully received.

Comment: Have you seen [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332410/roots-of-xn-xn-1-cdots-x-1)? It says "Proving this implies that $P(x)$ has $n$ roots in $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$". GH form MO gives a proof for your claim using Rouché's theorem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: thanks for the pointer: I did a lot of hunting for posts involving Rouché's theorem, but didn't find that one $\ddot{\frown}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that $g(x)=(x-1)f(x)=x^{r+1}-2x^{r}+1$ and look at its zeroes on the unit circle (we know $\alpha=1$ is a root of $g$ but clearly not of $f$, we will show there is no other). So let $g(\alpha)=0$ and $|\alpha|=1$, then
$$
1=|\alpha^{r+1}-2\alpha^r|=|\alpha|^r|\alpha-2|=|\alpha-2|.
$$
Only complex number that satisfies both $|\alpha|=1$ and $|\alpha-2|=1$ is $\alpha=1$ (can be seen either as an intersection of two circles in the complex plane, or solved fully algebraically if needed). So $g(x)$ has no other roots on the unit circle than the $\alpha=1$, and by the construction and the fact that $f(1) \neq 0$, $f(x)$ has no roots on the unit circle.

Comment: Excellent - many thanks.